# Splitting a column into multiple columns in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a Dictionary field in a MongoDB document which contains values that are separated by a semicolon. Is there any query that I could use to split the column into multiple columns.

The scenario is that I load in contents from a CSV file which sometimes has columns that are delimited by characters like a semicolon. Since I will have to support any kind of input CSV file, I cannot fix anything in the schema. Thus I have a dictionary field called "content" that stores the document contents as a dictionary. Now I need to be able to perform splits on columns that have multiple values.

Eg: Author Names column has entries like Author1;Author2;Author3. The user should be able to split this into 3 columns - one for each author.

**Edit**: For now, I have implemented this by means of a process on the server side. Ideally it would be great if I can do this in MongoDB itself (speed constraints).

Comment: you can process after the find. Also you can look into virtuals in mongoose.

Comment: I'm new to MongoDB. Could you say a little more?

Comment: explain your scenario in question. why do you need to split. whats the objective?

Comment: I was saying, it is possible when you do find and start to loop over the results. Just do a split on the field with the delimeter you need and you will have the results. Regarding having it done at the query level i have no idea. But mongoose which is a ODM on mongodb supports virtual fieilds which look silimilar. But I personally dont prefer mongoose as it is a too much schema thing.

Comment: No. You can't do this as part of a query. You will have to split the results with client-code. The best path is to fix the data import somehow - you can't call it a CSV if it's semicolon-delimited in whole or in part, for example.

Comment: Yup, I had to do this myself. The thing is that the input file is already a comma separated file. Particular fields in the CSV might be delimited in some other way that I want to exploit.